# how to customize textinputlayout?

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout

Hi I am using **TextInputLabel** in my app.I want to customize this. When it is normal I want to set the **font** and text **size** as **open sans regular** and 14 sp respectively.When user type something I want to change the size of floating label to 12sp and font of text inside the dittext as open sans light. And I want to adjust the space between floating label and text in edittext. Is it possible? Then how?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Mark Allison's article](https://blog.stylingandroid.com/textinputlayout/). He explains at the end how to customise the error text - the hint text is just the same but using the `app:hintTextAppearance` attribute.